# keywords in array in C

Tags: c, keyword

I'm having trouble getting keywords into an array. This is my array:

```
char keywords [] = {'auto', 'break', 'case', 'char', 'continue', 'do', 'default', 'const', 'double', 'else', 'enum', 'extern', 'for', 'if', 'goto', 'float', 'int', 'long', 'register', 'return', 'signed', 'static', 'sizeof', 'short', 'struct', 'switch', 'typedef', 'union', 'void', 'while', 'volatile', 'unsigned'};
```

but whenever I run my program I keep getting

```
warning: overflow in implicit constant 
coversion [-Woverflow]
```

error.

Does anyone know what this error means or how I can successfully get the C keywords into an array?

Comment: String literals in C are denoted with double quotes (for example, `"str"`), not with single quotes, which are used for denoting single characters (for example, `'c'`). Your mistake probably stems from your knowledge in Python or in Javascript, where both types of quotes can be used for that purpose.

Comment: BTW, it's not really clear what you mean by `get the C keywords into an array`, but this statement implies that you believe that you can later "use" them somehow from that array. If you meant to just store **the names** of these keywords as strings, then that's fine. But don't expect to be able to "evaluate" them during runtime or something (if that's what you had in mind).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use single quotes `'` to delimit strings in c, for that you need double qoutes `"`.

And you need an array of pointers, so your declaration should be `char *keywords[]`

```
const char *keywords[] = {
    "auto", 
    "break", 
    "case", 
    "char", 
    "continue", 
    "do", 
    "default", 
    "const", 
    "double", 
    "else", 
    "enum", 
    "extern", 
    "for", 
    "if", 
    "goto", 
    "float", 
    "int", 
    "long", 
    "register", 
    "return", 
    "signed", 
    "static", 
    "sizeof", 
    "short", 
    "struct", 
    "switch", 
    "typedef", 
    "union", 
    "void", 
    "while", 
    "volatile", 
    "unsigned"
};
```

single quotes are used for character constants, and there exist **multi-character** character constants but those are implementation defined, a single character **character constant** like `'a'` gives an integer value which is the ascii code of that character.

It seems that you are trying to write a parser, have you considered using `bison` + `flex` or any other parser generator?

Comment: `char keywords []` -> `const char *keywords []`